# How to change the settings of a video?

Tags: css, html, videos

I'm having real trouble with a video I have placed on my wordpress site. It's a one page site with the divi theme, and I currently don't have any type of video plugin activated. The video is an offline mp4 file (NOT a youtube video/link) that I have uploaded from my computer onto the webpage (NOT a blog).

There's several things I need the video to do:

1. Starting playing automatically WITHOUT the user having to click any sort of play button.
2. Play on a continuous loop
3. Hide the progress bar (including sound and full screen options) at the bottom so it's just the playing video we can see.

My coding skills are very minimal, and I can't seem to find & edit the HTML. I've only come across CSS. Anyone who can help me with this problem, I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you add your video? Is it in your themes code? Added via Divi editor? Inserted in the normal WP post editor via the media library? It's not clear what you mean when you say you added the video

Comment: Closed as this is a Divi theme builder question

Comment: how do I closed a question?

Comment: You need Divi specific expertise for your problem, ask in the Divi community they'll know more about how to do this

Answer (score 1):

> My coding skills are very minimal, and I can't seem to find & edit the HTML.

This is because video embeds are usually implemented using a shortcode, there is no HTML to edit, it's generated on the fly

> Starting playing automatically WITHOUT the user having to click any sort of play button.

yes and no... you can tell the shortcode to specify autoplay like this:

```
[video ... autoplay="on"]
```

But the browser will probably prevent this unless you meet a number of restrictions. For example, having no sound. Different browsers may have different rules.

Note that autoplaying will use mobile bandwidth, and that the browser or device may be unable to play the video due to its format.

> Play on a continuous loop

Yes, add the `loop` parameter:

https://wordpress.org/support/article/video-shortcode/

```
[video ... loop="on"]
```

> Hide the progress bar (including sound and full screen options) at the bottom so it's just the playing video we can see.

This can be done using CSS alone, just inspect the parts you don't want and write a CSS rule with `display: none;`

Note that Divi may be providing its own video player, consult the divi docs ( divi support is offtopic here ) if that's the case

Comment: The video is an mp4 file and is a minute long. It features a house being built and needs to run fully.

Comment: @GeorgiaBarber I don't believe it's possible to just give you a snippet of code to make it just work, e.g. here are the rules Chrome announced for stopping auto-playing videos https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: eitherway what you want cannot be done with the UI, and may not even be possible ( e.g. if your video has audio, even if it's just an empty audio track ). WP's video embeds just aren't that flexible

Comment: @GeorgiaBarber I've updated my answer having done some further digging

Comment: I see your updated answer. But how do I insert these shortcodes/parameters? In terms of code all I can see is a lot of complicated CSS, PHP. No sign of HTML

Comment: In your editor, where you added the video. If you added it using the divi editor then I cannot help, you will need to go to the Divi support routes. This answer and all comments assumes the standard WordPress editor ( classic/block based ), if you're using the divi editor then that's a major piece of info that needs clarifying. For the record, you should not be seeing PHP when you go to edit a post in WP Admin, If you're talking about a video tag that is in your themes PHP files, that's a completely different story, and one that will need you to update your question to clarify

Comment: the website i'm editing I was given control of by a professional web designer. She built the website using a Divi Theme/Builder. I have inserted the video as a module if that makes sense?

Comment: Not really, I'm not familiar with Divi theme builder, you'll need to contact Divi support and refer to Divi documentation, it sounds like a Divi specific thing, not something that general WordPress stuff can help with